# Adding each element in an array to a complex hash in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array with n number of elments. I want to add each of the elements to a complex hash, each as a key/value pair. If the number of elements were fixed, say three, I would do:

```
my %hash;
my @array = ("first", "second", "third");
$hash{$array[0]}{$array[1]}{$array[2]}++;
```

The structure I want to end up with, is this (printed with Data::Dumper):

```
$VAR1 = 'first';
$VAR2 = {
        'second' => {
                   'third' => 1
};
```

But I am at loss at achieving the same structure when the number of elements in the array isn't fixed. Something with anonymous variables and iterating through the array, yes, but something like

```
foreach @array{$hash{$_}++};
```

will obviously only make one entry per element, and not the desired structure. Help?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this could build the structure you desire for N elements:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper;
my @array = qw(first second third four five six seven);

my $hash;
foreach my $key ( reverse @array ) {
   $hash = { $key => $hash };
}
print Dumper $hash;

__END__
$VAR1 = {
      'first' => {
                   'second' => {
                                 'third' => {
                                              'fourth' => {
                                                          'fifth' => {
                                                                      'sixth' => {
                                                                                 'seventh' => undef
                                                                               }
                                                                    }
                                                        }
                                            }
                               }
                 }
    };
```

It is not clear what you really *need* this for. There may be a better solution if you explain your use-case a little more. Incrementing this structure doesn't appear to be very easy.

After playing around a little, you can increment by traversing the hash reference to the bottom then incrementing the value of the last element. It is not very pretty though :|

```
# incrementing
my $elem = $hash; # copy the reference 
foreach my $key ( @array ) {
   # found the bottom of the hash
   unless ( $elem->{$key} && ref($elem->{$key}) ) { 
      $elem->{$key}++;
      last; 
   }

   # not at the bottom, move to the next level
   $elem = $elem->{$key};
}
print Dumper $hash;

__END__
$VAR1 = {
      'first' => {
                   'second' => {
                                 'third' => {
                                              'fourth' => {
                                                            'fifth' => {
                                                                         'sixth' => {
                                                                                      'seventh' => 1
                                                                                    }
                                                                       }
                                                          }
                                            }
                               }
                 }
    };
```

Comment: My goal is to count occurrences of ngrams in a text. E.g, in the sentence "under a rock, and under a tree", the combinations of two words following each other would be "under a, a rock, rock and, and under, under a, a tree". Then I want the frequency of each two(or three, or four)-word combinations. In that sentence, all the so-called bigrams will have the value 1 (number of occurrences), while "a rock" will have a value of 2, because it occurrs two times.

Text::Ngrams would probalby work, but I am interessted in the theory behind it.

Comment: If you want to conserve space in such a way this is fine, but I am not sure of a good way to perform your count. I wrote a simpleish n-gram generator awhile ago that might provide a decent example: https://github.com/mcmillhj/markov-perl/Chain.pm

Comment: @vetinari: If that is your goal then you cannot use simple nested hashes like this. You need `$hash{under}{a}` to have a count of its own, as well as being another hash reference so that you can have a count in `$hash{under}{a}{rock}`

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively simple if you maintain a *current hash* reference. This short program demonstrates

The first few steps make sure that each hash element exists and its value is a hash reference. `$href` is moved to the next level of hash at each stage. For the final element of the array, the latest hash level's element is incremented instead of being set to a hash reference.

Whether or not this data structure is the correct choice depends on what else you need to do with it once you have built it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my @array = qw/ first second third fourth fifth /;

drill_hash(\%hash, @array);

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash;

sub drill_hash {
  my ($href, @list) = @_;
  my $final = pop @list;
  $href = $href->{$_} //= {} for @list;
  ++$href->{$final};
}
```

**output**

```
{
  first => { second => { third => { fourth => { fifth => 1 } } } },
}
```

---

**Update**

Having understood your purpose, the simplest way to keep a count of occurrences of ngrams like that is to have a speficic hash key that is used to keep the *count* of the sequence of words so far.

This program uses the value `_COUNT` for that key, and you can see that, for example, `{under}{a}{_COUNT}` and `{under}{a}{rock}{_COUNT}` are both 1

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %counts;

count_ngram(\%counts, qw/ under a /);
count_ngram(\%counts, qw/ a rock /);
count_ngram(\%counts, qw/ under a rock /);
count_ngram(\%counts, qw/ a tree /);
count_ngram(\%counts, qw/ under a tree /);

use Data::Dump;
dd \%counts;

sub count_ngram {
  my ($href, @ngram) = @_;
  my $final = pop @ngram;
  $href = $href->{$_} //= {} for @ngram;
  ++$href->{$final}{_COUNT};
}
```

**output**

```
{
  a => { rock => { _COUNT => 1 }, tree => { _COUNT => 1 } },
  under => {
    a => { _COUNT => 1, rock => { _COUNT => 1 }, tree => { _COUNT => 1 } },
  },
}
```

Comment: this one looks a lot cleaner than what I suggested.